# Make a random mac address generator generate just unicast macs

Tags: java, networking, mac-address

This is my simple mac address generator:

```
private String randomMACAddress(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
    rand.nextBytes(macAddr);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(18);
    for(byte b : macAddr){
        if(sb.length() > 0){
            sb.append(":");
        }else{ //first byte, we need to set some options
            b = (byte)(b | (byte)(0x01 << 6)); //locally adminstrated
            b = (byte)(b | (byte)(0x00 << 7)); //unicast

        }
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }


    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note how I set and unset bits to make so it generates unicast macs.
However it doesn't work and my automated program which accepts mac addresses returns me an error because "this mac address is multicast".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved...I just made

```
private String randomMACAddress(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
    rand.nextBytes(macAddr);

    macAddr[0] = (byte)(macAddr[0] & (byte)254);  //zeroing last 2 bytes to make it unicast and locally adminstrated

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(18);
    for(byte b : macAddr){

        if(sb.length() > 0)
            sb.append(":");

        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }


    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Zeroing last bit  will make it unicast however for it to be seen as locally administered the second last bit of MSB should be '1' : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Answer (score 0):

If the least significant bit of the most significant address octet is set to 1, the frame will still be sent only once; however, NICs will choose to accept it based on criteria other than the matching of a MAC address: for example, based on a configurable list of accepted multicast MAC addresses. This is called multicast addressing.

Comment: So...it is the inverse? Correcting this line b = (byte)(b | (byte)(0x00 << 7)); //unicast with 0x01 will do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String generateRandomMacAddress() {
      Random r = new Random();
      return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(1) + r.nextInt(11)+ ":" +
              r.nextInt(11) + r.nextInt(11) + ":" +
              RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(2)+":"+
              r.nextInt(11)+RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(1)+":"+
              r.nextInt(11)+RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(1);
   }
```

``

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For a random MAC address, here's nearly a one liner

```dart
import 'dart:math';

Random r = Random();
String mac = List.generate(6, (_) => r.nextInt(256).toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(":");

print("mac is $mac"); // mac is 8f:e0:63:e0:92:60
```